how to get 15 rep here so I can vote?
I don't have much questions that hasn't been answered in google already and I don't have answers cuz i'm noob. I want to be able to vote to mark the posts I've already visited.

Hello and Welcome. For Questions about this site, the network, moderation, rules and how they work, please use Meta instead.

See https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation
